# How to force a line break in a legend of a boxplot?

Tags: matlab, legend, boxplot

I need help to skip lines in the legend of boxplots : I have a plot with two boxplots, and each of them has a legend to long to fit on a single line.

I tried this, X being my matrix of data (two colums) :

```
boxplot(X,'Labels',{'1stpartofthelegend\newline2ndpartofthelegend','1stpartofthelegend\newline2ndpartofthelegend})
```

This solution works in other types of plots, like a plotspread plot so I don't understand why it is not working here ?
I found [this question](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101117-how-do-i-make-a-figure-legend-multiple-lines-in-matlab-7-11-r2010b), but the solutions are not working for me, maybe because I have a more recent version (R2018b).

I actually want to add my boxplots over a plotpsread plot, but when I do that the legends of the boxplots win over the legends of the plotspread (even if I add boxplots without legends, the previous legends of the plotspread are replaced by "1" and "2"). So preventing the boxplot to erase the previous legend would be a nice solution but as I failed to do that I tried to find another way.

Thank you for your help

Comment: The title irritates me. Do you want to *skip* a line i.e. an entry in the legend or do you want to have a *line break* in one of your legend entries? (the latter may work with cells where each element is a new line)

Comment: @max I edited the title for more clarity.

Comment: By `legend`, do you mean `XtickLabels`?

Comment: Instead of `\newline` insert an actual new line character: `['text', char(13), 'more text']`. I guess your solution doesn’t work here because the legend is not configured to interpret LaTeX. Changing that setting might also fix it.

Comment: char(13) did not work in my case, it is only removed in the labels. However the solution of @max with the cell of cells was a success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the `'Labels'` of the boxplot for multiple lines. So use a cell of cells:

```
Lbl = { {'1st entry (1st line)','2nd entry (1st line)'},...
        {'1st entry (2nd line)','2nd entry (2nd line)'} };
boxplot(rand(100,2),'Labels',Lbl)
```

**EDIT**
LaTeX commands work in the title and labels but apparently there is no `interpreter` or `TickLabelInterpreter`  property for boxplot-`Labels`:

> Error using internal.stats.parseArgs (line 42)
>
> Invalid parameter name: TickLabelInterpreter.

Comment: Ticklabels do have interpreter property. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7_sep_shared-TickLabelInterpreter

Comment: @SardarUsama you are right, I should be more precise. There is no whatsoever-interpretor argument for boxplot labels. I corrected the post